# I'm Getting "invalid escape sequence in literal" error

Tags: macos, swift5, xcode12

I Get "invalid Escape Sequence in literal" on Swift 5.4 On Xcode 12.5.1 My Code is:

```
if flag == false {

print("\ (number ) is a prime number");

}else{

print("\ (number ) is not a prime number");
}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: There should not be a space between the backslash and `(`.

Comment: Thank you! I feel very stupid right now as I feel I should've figured that out myself